# JTable enable some checkbox column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a `jtable` I populated from a database , but I want to enable or gray out some of this jtable lines ( lines that exist in another table of the same database) for the user cannot check the `checkbox` of these lines, but the rest of the lines ( lines that do not exist in this table ) can always be checked.

```
for (int m = 0; m < tb_doublon.getRowCount(); m++) {
    Statement statdouble=null;  
    ResultSet rsdouble=null;

    //I get the value of the cell of the column 1 :id, line : i
    String id = (String)tb_doublon.getValueAt(m, 1);
    String cli = (String)tb_doublon.getValueAt(m, 2);

    //i browse the other table to enable or gray out the lines existing in that table with th id
    String doubleexistant ="select * from doublon where id='"+id+"' and cli='"+cli+"'" ;
    statdouble = conn.createStatement();
    rsdouble  = statdouble.executeQuery(doubleexistant);
    while (rsdouble.next()) {
      //i think this is here that i must enable or gray out the lines but i don't know how !!!!<br>             
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to create a customized table model. please add information about your table model. additionally i don't recommend to run sql statements inside a loop. you can manage it in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

sir, you can create your checkboxes in an array for accessing them easier.

```
JCheckBox [] checkboxes= new JCheckBox[WIDTH];
```

if you found 2nd index to be duplicate you can simply disable the 2nd checkbox in your array

```
checkboxes[1].setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloring a row can be perform using a modified `TableCellRenderer`. I have created a customized `TableCellRenderer` as follows.

**ColorTableRenderer.java**

It can add rows to be mark as gray, and clear all marked rows.

```
public class ColorTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    //contains row indexes which need to color
    private final List<Integer> colorIndexes = new ArrayList<>();

    //add new index to show as color
    public void addColorIndex(Integer index) {
        colorIndexes.add(index);
    }

    //clear all color indexes
    public void clearColorIndexes() {
        colorIndexes.clear();
    }

    private boolean isColorIndex(Integer index) {
        return colorIndexes.contains(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component component = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (isColorIndex(row)) {//check if marked as colored
            component.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);//highlight color
        } else {
            component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);//other color
        }

        return component;
    }
}
```

**Using the ColorTableRenderer**

Set the `ColorTableRenderer` to the table using one of following methods.

```
    ColorTableRenderer renderer = new ColorTableRenderer();

    //set TableCellRenderer into a specified JTable column class
    table.setDefaultRenderer(String[].class, renderer);

    //or, set TableCellRenderer into a specified JTable column
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

Considering your code, you can add following modifications to make selected row color.

```
    renderer.clearColorIndexes();
    for (int m = 0; m < tb_doublon.getRowCount(); m++) {
        Statement statdouble = null;
        ResultSet rsdouble = null;

        //I get the value of the cell of the column 1 :id, line : i
        String id = (String) tb_doublon.getValueAt(m, 1);
        String cli = (String) tb_doublon.getValueAt(m, 2);

        //i browse the other table to enable or gray out the lines existing in that table with th id
        String doubleexistant = "select * from doublon where id='" + id + "' and cli='" + cli + "'";
        statdouble = conn.createStatement();
        rsdouble = statdouble.executeQuery(doubleexistant);
        while (rsdouble.next()) {
            renderer.addColorIndex(m);
        }
    }
```

This is my tested screen-shot

[image: Color Table Cell Test]